# how do you design an OLAP system to power a dashboard of hourly (or even more granular) API usage stats

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, etl, data-warehouse

For background, I collect API usage logs (request, response, latency, userId, etc) for an application. A typical day will accumulate 200-300 million records.  This data is currently stored on s3 in parquet format, and I use AWS Athena for ad-hoc querying.  I'd like to move towards building a web-based dashboard that would display per customer metrics; an example query would be request volume by customer by hour for the past 6 hours.  I'll only need that kind of detailed usage data for the previous 30 days.

Ideally, I continue to utilize the AWS ecosystem for this solution. What I'm trying to determine is a general direction. Can Redshift efficiently compute those types of queries against the raw log data, on the fly, within 1s or so to make it usable on the web? Is there a better tool? Or should I be looking at running ETLs and rollup type operations to generate those metrics, populate a different table (perhaps in redshift) and then use that to serve the dashboard?

Any thoughts, or even suggested readings, are welcome - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are a log of approaches you can take to this kind of problem, I'll try to detail some of the products you could use based upon your problem above.

- Preprocess anything you can rather than calculate on the fly. Summarise your hourly metrics for example in a key value store rather than computing across large numbers of metrics. You could efficiently store these metrics in [DynamoDB](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/) and retrieve.
- [Redshift](https://aws.amazon.com/redshift/) can return data quickly depending on your schema definitions (distribution keys, sort keys), however if you are writing individual transactions will be not be as efficient with the writes. You will want to do this bulk for periods. It will need to be settled as a near real-time solution.
- Common dashboards that require large computation but do not need to be live (i.e. hourly or daily stats) can be generated and stored in [S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/), therefore it will be fast but not require to be read from the DB every time the user.
- [Athena](https://aws.amazon.com/athena/?whats-new-cards.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&whats-new-cards.sort-order=desc) is for querying a data lake, if you use this for large portions of near real time data it will not be as efficient at getting the data results to you. In saying this if you use Redshift you can join queries from your data lake using [Redshift Spectrum](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c-getting-started-using-spectrum.html).